# nested if vs. if with double ampersand?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, nested

When is the proper time to use a nested if loop

```
if(a){
  if(b){
```

over an if statement with a && operator inside the braces?

```
if(a && b){
```

Both's tasks are utilized to test 2 conditions and are true if both meet the conditions.

Is the nested if statement used for iterating over arrays like the nested for?

Comment: An if statement is not a loop.

Answer (score 12):

> When is the proper time to use a nested if loop
>
> ```
> if(a){ if(b){
> ```
>
> over an if statement with a && operator inside the braces?
>
> ```
> if(a && b){
> ```

For a start `if(a){ if(b){` is not a "nested if loop".  It is a nested if *statement*.  (Or at least the `if (b) { ...` part is the nested statement.)

The word "loop" in IT implies that something repeats.  There is no repetition here.

(Sorry to be pedantic, but when you use basic terms like this incorrectly, it strongly suggests that either you don't know what the term means, or you don't understand whatever it is that you've incorrectly applied the term to.)

---

As other answers have explained, the two forms

```
 if(a){ if(b){
```

and

```
 if(a && b){
```

do the same thing.  So which one should you use?  It boils down to two things:

- Readability: depending on what `a` and `b` are (i.e. in a real program), one form is likely to be more readable than the other *to the average Java programmer*.  The difference in readability may be marginal, or it may be substantial.
- Personal taste: some programmers favour one form over the other, for ... personal reasons.

There are a couple of *non-reasons*:

- Style guides: as far as I'm aware no Java style guide mandates one form over another.
- Efficiency: as far as I'm aware, there is no systematic difference in performance between the two versions<sup>1</sup>.

---

Finally ...

> Is the nested if statement used for iterating over arrays like the nested for

No.  Nested if statements are not loops.  They don't iterate.

Of course, you can *use* nested if statements as part of some larger piece of code that iterates ... but there is nothing magical about that.

The bottom line is that constructs like `if`, `while`, `for`, blocks, declarations, assignments, and so are *general purpose* constructs that can be used for an infinite number of different things.  The most important thing is to understand what they do.  Once you know that, the various things you can use them for become self-evident ... if you think about the algorithms you are trying to implement.

---

<sup>1 - The bytecodes for the two versions may be superficially different.  However, that will mean nothing.  The JIT compiler *should* be able to optimize both versions to native code that performs the same.  If it can't, that is a JIT compiler flaw which should be addressed in a future release of Java.</sup>

Comment: In the single if case, when you use it with else. Else will run only if both a & b are true. However in the case of nested if, else will run even if only condition a is met.

Comment: Well yes ... but this question doesn't involve if / else.  It is about if within if versus if with &&.

Answer (score 3):

Which one you choose matters when accompanied by an `else`.

In the single `if` case, when you use it with `else`, `else` will run if either `a` or `b` are `false`. However in the case of nested `if`s, `else` will run only if `a` is false, because the program is already in the `if` branch when evaluating `b`.

Here’s an example:

```swift
var a = true
var b = false

// First Case (Single-Line)
if a && b {
    print("foo");
} else {
    print("bar");
}
// Output: "bar"

// Second Case (Nested)
if a {
    if b {
        print("foo");
    }
} else {
    print("bar")
}
// No output
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this

```
if(a) {
    if(b) {
       ...
    }
}
```

will be equivalent to

```
if(a && b) {
    ... 
}
```

i.e. when `a` is `true`, test `b`, and if it is also `true` run code.

Both codes will have same complexities.
If you don't need to do anything after `a` is true then definitely second code will be suitable and vice-versa.

Comment: And what am I misunderstanding exactly?

Comment: @Dimoff Please accept [StephenC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57129396/3626698). It better address Question. I want to delete this answer

Answer (score -3):

If you want to test both conditions together, do `a || b`. If you want to test each condition individually, do `if(a) { if (b) { } }`.

For example:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        // Both true.
    } else {
        // Only a.
    }
} else {
    if (b) {
        // Only b.
    } else {
        // Neither true.
    }
}
```

Comment: I want them both to be true, I guess that excludes the pipe operator, no?

Comment: @nosille The `||` operator is named `conditional OR operator` for this context.

Comment: Both the conditions aren't tested together, read about short-circuiting. Basically, if the first condition passes then in || the second condition will not even be executed.