# python "and" keyword vs nested if-statements

Tags: python, if-statement

For the following two code:

```
if a and b:
    then do something

if a:
    if b:
        then do something
```

What is the difference between these two statements in terms of semantics and the time it takes to execute? Do not both of them always evaluate the same? And is one of them faster than the other (I am not asking asymptotically, not the big O notation)?

Byte code with **and**:

```
  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

  8     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Nested statement:

```
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

 11           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8

 12     >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Edit:**
If I'm not making a mistake, they are generating exactly the same bytecode.

Comment: The two versions do exactly the same thing. The difference in speed can usually be ignored. For readability I prefer `if a and b` to make indentation shallower.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197966/nested-if-vs-if-with-double-ampersand)

Comment: What you've written are equivalent. But if you add `else:` statements they won't be.

Comment: @PrakashDahal Seem different questions to me

Answer (score 2):

They have the exact same semantics.

See [6.11. Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in the language specification:

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

And [8.1. The `if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement):

> It selects exactly one of the suites by evaluating the expressions one by one until one is found to be true (see section Boolean operations for the definition of true and false); then that suite is executed (and no other part of the if statement is executed or evaluated).

No tricky combination of implementations of `__bool__` and `__and__` (which is the operator `&`, not `and`) methods can change this.

I wouldn't be concerned about any performance difference; if you need to worry about such nano-optimizations, don't use Python in the first place.

Comment: The question is not python specific actually, you can do the same in C with "&&". I wonder which one is faster not because I prefer the faster one to the other but because I would guess that nested statements would take more time

Comment: @goku Why don't you look at the generated byte code?

Comment: @goku use `dis.dis()` to find out which involves more work. `and` will short-circuit so I doubt there's anything in it but not at my pc right now

Comment: And in what case they will have different results?

Comment: I edited the question, nested statement seems to be doing less work @rojangosh

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that the bytecode there is for your question. It has to load each value twice in a local scope? Hmm

Comment: Yep small mistake, edited again @roganjosh

Comment: If it really is the case then I must say that it's a surprising outcome!

Comment: It was my mistake in the first place. But, it is interesting to me that they have exactly the same bytecode @roganjosh

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing code, you should look first that you can understand the code later on. So I would choose the first type of the if-statement. I think, you would execute this code on a rather powerful PC and you wouldn't notice any speed differences at all.

Just look, that the code is clean and readable to ensure, that you do not make extra long complicated logic. Bad ways of logic implementation will take much longer to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics are exactly the same. How they are interpreted, and specifically how fast the interpretation will be depend on the specific interpreter/compiler (i.e. on the python distribution).

As a side note, if you are not interested in asymptotic complexity, then you already have your answer: they run in perceivably the same amount of time.